# Gallery item background not changed with setSelection

Tags: java, android, gallery, selector

I have a Gallery with text items. I can change the selected item with the UI or programmatically with setSelection(position). However when I call this method, sometimes the item background is not changed to a selected state. I noticed that if the item called by setSelection is already drawn on the screen then its background is not updated.

Here is the code. Any help is welcome.

```
public class Test3 extends Activity {

  private static String[] items = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};

  public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout (this);
    layout.setOrientation (LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    setContentView (layout);
    final Gallery gallery = new Gallery (this);
    layout.addView (gallery);
    gallery.setSpacing (0);
    gallery.setAdapter (new Adapter (this));
    gallery.setSelection (0);
    ListView list = new ListView (this);
    layout.addView (list);
    list.setAdapter (new ArrayAdapter <String> (this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));
    list.setOnItemClickListener (new OnItemClickListener () {
      public void onItemClick (AdapterView <?> parent, View view, int position,
      long id)
      {
        gallery.setSelection (position);
      }
    });
  }

  private class Adapter extends ArrayAdapter <String> {

    public Adapter (Context context) {
      super (context, android.R.layout.simple_gallery_item, items);
    }

    public View getView (int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent)
    {
      TextView view = new TextView (getContext ());
      view.setText (getItem (position));
      view.setBackgroundResource (R.drawable.gallery_background);
      view.setGravity (Gravity.CENTER);
      view.setLayoutParams (new Gallery.LayoutParams (Test3.this
      .getWindowManager ().getDefaultDisplay ().getWidth () / 3,
      Gallery.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
      return view;
    }
  }
}
```

gallery_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/highlight_selected" />
  <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/highlight_selected" />
  <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/highlight_selected" />
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/highlight_pressed" />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/highlight_disabled" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Still open for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `invalidating` the gallery or `notifyDataSetChanged` the galleries adapter.

Comment: I tried invalidate and refreshDrawableState with no luck... But it works with `((ArrayAdapter <String>) gallery.getAdapter ()).notifyDataSetChanged ()`. I mark this answer as useful, but I wait a little before accepting it because it looks like a hack to me...

Comment: Is not really a hack. notifyDataSetChanged tells the view that something (non specfic) in the view adapter has changed and that it should probably update it self. If you ever added or removed adapter items this is how you refresh the view.

Comment: Yes but in this case I didn't change any item.